# made a program in python but get TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pyowm
import datetime
import csv

W = pyowm.OWM("****************************")
myHouse = W.weather_at_place("St. albert,Canada")
myWeather = myHouse.get_weather()
wind = myWeather.get_wind()
windspeed = wind["speed"]
windangle = wind["deg"]
humidity = myWeather.get_humidity()
temperature = myWeather.get_temperature("celsius")
high = temperature["temp_max"]
low = temperature["temp_min"]
current = temperature["temp"]
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%D")
time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H")

done=0

while True:
    if datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S") == "00" and done == 0:
        done=1
        csvfile = open("weatherCSV.csv", "w")
        writeCSV = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")

        myWeather = myHouse.get_weather()
        wind = myWeather.get_wind
        windspeed = wind["speed"]
        windangle = wind["deg"]
        humidity = myWeather.get_humidity()
        temperature = myWeather.get_temperature("celsius")
        high = temperature["temp_max"]
        low = temperature["temp_min"]
        current = temperature["temp"]
        date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%D")
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H")


        writeCSV.writerow([current,high,low,windspeed,windangle,humidity,date,time])
        csvfile.close()
        print("Added to file")

    if datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%S") == "30" and done == 1:
        done=0
```

> this is my program, it should be fine since wind is a dictionnary and temperature works just fine but i get error:

```
...$ python weather.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weather.py", line 29, in <module>
    windspeed = wind["speed"]
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

> by the way line 29 is:

```
windspeed = wind["speed"]
```

> inside the while True: and the if ... : loops. I would very much like to know why this doesn't work and how to make it work because it seems to be running that code just fine the first time, outside the loops.
>   this is running on python 3.6.1 on the latest MacOs.

Comment: Use `wind = myWeather.get_wind()`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to help you since we don’t know what type of your variable. You can try to either print type of your wind object to see or print(wind) itself. My guess is wind here is returned as a method and not exactly dictionary type as you want.

Also inside the loop your get_wind is missing () which makes Python does not understand you are calling the method and think you are calling variable inside the object